# After removing mysql, when I execute mysql my prompt changes?

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I am not sure why this is happening.

I made a mistake and I installed mysql with brew, then I forgot and I installed again but with the dmg package.

Then I wanted to remove completely both and make a new fresh install.

I followed this steps Remove MySQL completely per The Tech Lab

I realized that the step of editing /etc/hostconfig does not exists.

After finishing the removing steps and restarting, if I try to execute mysql and it should not work, but instead it changes the prompt to this

```
~mysql
```

I am not sure how to completely remove mysql.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can locate it with the command `which mysql` - once you know where it is, you will be able to remove it.